# Problema al mandar parametros en React por medio de un dispatch

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Tengo un componente que falla en mi componentDidMount al momento de hacer un dispatch a un action de Redux que tengo.

Componente.

```
constructor(props){
  super(props);

  this.state = {
     orders: {
      status: 1
     }
   }
 }
componentDidMount(){
  const { dispatch } = this.props;
  let { orders } = this.state;

  dispatch(orders.showOrders(orders));
}
```

Action

```
export const orders = {
  showOrders
}

function showOrders(params){
   console.log(params);
}
```

El problema es que me tira el siguiente error:

```
TypeError: orders.showOrders is not a function
```

Sin embargo, me di cuenta que cuando comento la línea de `let { orders }` y añado un objeto donde mando a llamar la función (action) de showOrders funciona, el código se ejecuta correctamente.

Curiosamente, trate de asignar a una variable un objeto y añadirla donde mando a llamar la función de showOrders y me tira el mismo error. ¿A qué se debe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu mismo te respondiste jeje, el problema es que en la función `componentDidMount` declaraste una variable `orders`, y en ese ámbito `orders` no es el objeto con tu action, sino que es la porción del state del componente!

Cambiale el nombre al objeto de tus actions (a ordersActions por ejemplo) o al objeto de tu state para arreglar el problema.